# Polish spelling variants for "Yechezkel Fleker"

Tags: surnames, poland, naming-convention, hebrew

I am trying to locate any records about my grand father.

His name in "Yechezkel Fleker" or in hebrew "יחזקאל פלקר" and I am trying to search some polish archives for information about him.

I am not sure what alternate spellings should I use for both his first name and surname.

I tried both Yechezkel & Ezekiel
and used http://www.origins.net/namex/NameXSearch.aspx
to get some alternate spellings but I am looking for some source that is more aware of the polish language features.

Thanks

Comment: Are you expecting to find records for him in Poland or in the US or both? Providing some more information (including the sources you have for that information) would help. Also listing things you tried that were not effective might help reduce duplication of effort.

Comment: I am looking for polish records. he never went to the US. He went to Israel.

Comment: B.T.W - on his way to Israel I know they where also in Russia and Austria. I will probably try to find any possible documents related to the time they spent at those places.

Comment: In Polish records he could also be 'Ezechiel', as this is the spelling used by Polish catholics. 'Fleker' would most likely stay unchanged.

Answer (score 7):

Using many of the suggestions here It seems like I managed to find at http://jri-poland.org a reference to my grandfathers birth with the spelling `Ichezkel Fleker`.

Next task is to see if I can get my hands on an actual birth certificate.

Answer (score 6):

One thing to do is look in the [JewishGen Given Names database](http://www.jewishgen.org/databases/GivenNames/search.htm) that might help with suggesting alternate "offical" names.

The more complicated answer is that depending on where you are searching for your ancestor's name, you might need to try different things. For example, if you are looking through ships' manifests, you have to keep in mind that someone from Poland who emigrated to the US around the turn of the 18th-19th century likely went through a German port of departure. Thus you should be looking for "Germanified" spellings of names. This Germanification might not affect the way Polish names are written as much at it would affect Russian names, but it's possible that your ancestor was a Russian speaker.

Some databases support [Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) indexing, so that may help match with inexact spelling; when that's not an option, try searching with just the strong consonants: `fl*k*r` for `Fleker` for example. In my experience, these tend to survive mispronunciation and mistranscription better than other letters.

Comment: I tried this page but was unable to get any results for the names I mentioned... :(

Comment: You might want to send it as a question to the JewishGen discussion list.

Comment: Names were generally written on passenger lists as provided by the identification documents of the traveller. (Granted that other alphabets posed difficulties). My German relatives from Transylvania need to be searched using the Hungarian and Romanian forms of the their names (esp. first names) as well as the German, depending on when the trip was taken. I haven't seen any patterns that depend on whether the port was German, French, Belgian, Dutch, etc. (I plan to check that out). The more significant search issue is bad indexing, which may need extreme creativity to overcome.

Answer (score 6):

For the first name "Yechezkel", try [Behind the Name](http://www.behindthename.com/name/yechezkel). It says that it is the Hebrew form of ["Ezekiel"](http://www.behindthename.com/name/ezekiel) and gives a number of variants for the name.

If you look up ["Polish Yechezkel" on Google](http://www.google.ca/search?q=polish%20Yechezkel), I think you'll find that there are many sites where the name "Yechezkel" is given. You'll likely have success with that name, once you search records that actually contain your grandfather.

For "Fleker", despite its Argentine bias the Hebrew Surnames site has [good information and a list of variances](http://www.hebrewsurnames.com/FLEKER). You can try some of the more plausible variations they give there.